# R: Restructure a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have several objects with an `id` (in the below example 1-3). For each of these objects every day their `status` is logged.

Some sample data:

```r
data <- data.frame(id =     c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2,  3, 3, 3, 3),
                   status = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3,  1, 2, 3, 4 ),
                   date = c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05",
                            "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04",
                            "2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", "2021-01-04"))

data
```

This looks like this:

```
   id status       date
1   1      1 2021-01-01
2   1      2 2021-01-02
3   1      2 2021-01-03
4   1      3 2021-01-04
5   1      4 2021-01-05
6   2      1 2021-01-02
7   2      2 2021-01-03
8   2      3 2021-01-04
9   3      1 2021-01-01
10  3      2 2021-01-02
11  3      3 2021-01-03
12  3      4 2021-01-04
```

For example on January second the status of object 1 turned from 1 to 2. On january third the status of object 1 didn't change. On January fourth it changed to status 3 etc.

How can I restructure that table, so that I have the changes between two days (`from` = the status of the day before, `to` = the status of the day after) in a form like this?

```
id  from   to   date
1   1      2    2021-01-02
1   2      2    2021-01-03
1   2      3    2021-01-04
1   3      4    2021-01-05

2   1      2    2021-01-03
2   2      3    2021-01-04

3   1      2    2021-01-02
3   2      3    2021-01-03
3   3      4    2021-01-04
```

Comment: Because I want the changes of the status variable from one day to another. On the first date there is no "before"

Comment: Can you check the updasted post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Group the data by 'id'
2. `summarise` to remove the last and first element of 'status' to create 'from', 'to' columns respectively, as well as remove the first element of 'date'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(from = status[-n()], to = status[-1],
         date = date[-1], .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
     id  from    to date      
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
1     1     1     2 2021-01-02
2     1     2     2 2021-01-03
3     1     2     3 2021-01-04
4     1     3     4 2021-01-05
5     2     1     2 2021-01-03
6     2     2     3 2021-01-04
7     3     1     2 2021-01-02
8     3     2     3 2021-01-03
9     3     3     4 2021-01-04
```

EDIT: Comments from @MartinGal

Comment: In your code "from" and "to" are always identical.

Comment: @akrun: are you overthinking the problem? `data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(from = lag(status), to = status) ` should do the trick (+slice, select, ungroup), or am I wrong?

Comment: @MartinGal I think you are right.  I was trying to understand the issue by some other logics

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(data)[, .(from = head(status, -1), to = tail(status, -1), date = tail(date, -1)), id]
```

gives

```
   id from to       date
1:  1    1  2 2021-01-02
2:  1    2  2 2021-01-03
3:  1    2  3 2021-01-04
4:  1    3  4 2021-01-05
5:  2    1  2 2021-01-03
6:  2    2  3 2021-01-04
7:  3    1  2 2021-01-02
8:  3    2  3 2021-01-03
9:  3    3  4 2021-01-04
```